# 14.04 doesn't mount digital camera

Tags: usb, 14.04, camera

I have a kodak digit camera that always has just mounted.  Since 14.04, it shows the device itself in `lsusb`.  Looking in `syslog` I see it recognizes the camera but then fails saying the device is not an `mtp`.  The exact log entries are:

```
May  9 21:57:12 davelaptop kernel: [ 1733.117649] usb 3-3: new full-speed USB device number 3 using ohci-pci
May  9 21:57:12 davelaptop kernel: [ 1733.316743] usb 3-3: New USB device found, idVendor=040a, idProduct=05d1
May  9 21:57:12 davelaptop kernel: [ 1733.316760] usb 3-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
May  9 21:57:12 davelaptop kernel: [ 1733.316769] usb 3-3: Product: KODAK EASYSHARE C182 Digital Camera
May  9 21:57:12 davelaptop kernel: [ 1733.316778] usb 3-3: Manufacturer: Eastman Kodak Company
May  9 21:57:12 davelaptop kernel: [ 1733.316785] usb 3-3: SerialNumber: C182 020552828
May  9 21:57:12 davelaptop mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 3: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb3/3-3"
May  9 21:57:12 davelaptop mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 3 was not an MTP device
May  9 21:57:12 davelaptop colord: Device added: sysfs-(null)
```

I also checked in `udev` and found some entries in hwdb folder about gphoto.  It did not have my camera listed.  I added it to 2 such rules files in that folder but it still doesn't mount.

My thought - I think something changed in `udev` and is messing this up.  I know there is a process there about probing `mtp` - perhaps that is failing also/instead?

I see this is not a unique problem.  There are lots of posts here and in the ubuntu forums about cameras not mounting.  Something is in common - some change from 13.10 to 14.04 is in common.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the problem is with mtp-probe which is not able to recognize your camera as Media Transfer Protocol MTP device : `mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 3 was not an MTP device`

I have the same problem with my Canon, Inc. Powershot S95 in Ubuntu 14.04 and used [gphotofs](http://www.gphoto.org/proj/gphotofs/) for a work-around. In a terminal I did the following:

1. Install gphotofs:
   `$ sudo apt-get install gphotofs`
2. then mount your camera, which I did under /tmp/camera
   `$ mkdir /tmp/camera/`
   `$ gphotofs /tmp/camera/`

That is it.

If gphotofs worked /tmp/camera/ should now be connected to your camera (check using either the terminal or nautilus). Lastly if you are using a photo manager like shotwell, use an `import from folder' option to access your pictures.

When you are finished importing your pictures you can unmount the camera folder:

`$ fusermount -u /tmp/camera/`

Comment: ~> sudo mkdir /media/camera
~> sudo gphotofs /media/camera
~> ls /media/camera
ls: cannot access /media/camera: Permission denied
~> ls /media/camera                                                   
ls: reading directory /media/camera: Protocol error

Answer (score 0):

Already had tried that and it didn't work.  Also tried several other things including modifying the databases.  As it turns out, a recent update fixed the problem - the thread on launchpad explains everything that has been happening to myself and others, and supposedly what the fix is/was.